# group by clause not grouping by

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

I have the following query written in MSSQL :

```
Select customer.name, 
max(callnote.ID), 
CAST (callnote.NOTE as VARCHAR(100)) 
from callnote   
join CONTACT        
    on
        contact.ID=callnote.CONTACT_ID  
join CUSTOMER       
    on
        customer.ID=contact.CUSTOMER_ID 
where callnote.TYPE='n' and CUSTOMER.AcctClass>='1' 
group by customer.NAME, CAST (callnote.NOTE as VARCHAR(100)) 
order by customer.NAME
```

I expect to only receive one record (the last note) per customer name. (789 rows, which I get when I leave the 'CAST (callnote.NOTE as VARCHAR(100))' out of the query)  What I am getting instead I believe is the last note per each contact (11,500+ rows). I've been racking my brain for hours and re-written this so many times. There is no common column between customer table and the callnote table. How do I get this to only show the last note per CUSTOMER?

Comment: you should read into the greatest n per group.... you are viewing the data incorrectly. if you want help with this you need to clarify the question and add data

Comment: Having string comparison like this is quite bad thing to have: AcctClass>='1' since '10' > '2' is not true because it's an alphabetical order comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up JamesZ ... You're completely right. I need to break the bad habit of quoting everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want the note from the note from the max callnote id? So something like this:

```
Select
  C.name, 
  n.ID,
  n.NOTE
from
  CUSTOMER c
  outer apply (
    select top 1
      callnote.ID, 
      CAST (callnote.NOTE as VARCHAR(100)) 
    from
      CONTACT   
      join callnote 
        on contact.ID=callnote.CONTACT_ID and callnote.TYPE='n'  
    where
      c.ID=contact.CUSTOMER_ID
    order by 
      callnote.ID desc) n
where 
  c.AcctClass>='1' 
order by 
  c.NAME
```

So this fetches always the row from the maximum id for that customer. Hopefully the syntax is ok, can't really test this.

Comment: Thank you Jamesz. That solution works beautifully. I never even knew 'outer apply' existed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
SELECT Name, MAX(CallNoteID) CallNoteID, CallNote
FROM
(
SELECT Customer.Name, 
       CallNote.ID CallNoteID, 
       TRIM(CAST(CallNote.Note as VARCHAR(100))) CallNote
FROM CallNote   
JOIN Contact ON Contact.ID = CallNote.CONTACT_ID  
JOIN Customer ON Customer.ID = Contact.CUSTOMER_ID 
WHERE CallNote.Type = 'n' AND Customer.AcctClass >= '1' 
) A
GROUP BY Name, CallNote 
ORDER BY Name
```